# "It is good for me." or "It is good to me."

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am confused between these two statements.

1. It is good for me.
2. It is good to me.

Which one is correct? or both are correct? When which statement should we use?

Comment: Both are correct but mean different things. Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/265961/edit) your post to provide context, or I'm afraid this question is unanswerable. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may be of interest to you.

Comment: This is obviously an unsuitable question for ELU. Who votes such questions up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

'Good for me' indicates that the object is beneficial to you e.g. 'medicine is good for me'

whereas

'Good to me' indicates that the object is kind or considerate to you e.g. 'my wife is good to me'

Both are correct, but the usage depends on your specific context.

Comment: maybe "object or person"?  I know there are objects as well as people that can be good *to * you—"Beisbol ben berry good to me"

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Objects can only be good **for** you, since being good **to** someone intends action. People can be referred to both ways.

Comment: In "baseball been good to me," *baseball* is the subject, not the object, of the sentence. Another thought here is that in the "for me" sentences (e.g. "food is good for me"), you can extend it (e.g. "food is good for me to eat") and even flip around (e.g. "it is good for me to eat food"). You can't do that with the "to me" sentences... (unless you're Yoda.)

Comment: What is I want to say, the apple looks good, from my point of view. Should I say "The apple looks good to me"?